# Ionic: reloading current child state from side menu causes loss of header

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm creating a simple Ionic menu app and I would like to **reload the current state from the side menu**.Here's a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/H5piRtg4QHXslrQSaHDp?p=preview) to illustrate the problem.

In the 'Search' state, the current time is displayed. The desired behavior is the following: when I click 'Search' from the side menu, the time is refreshed, i.e. the controller is reloaded. This should happen even when I'm already on the Search page. In reality, the controller is of course much more complex, but this example is enough to illustrate the problem.

I started from the ionic 'menu' starter template. To be able to reload the state, I changed two things:

1. **disabled view caching** in app.js config function: `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`
2. In menu.html, I'm passing `ui-sref-opts` to explicitly **reload** the state:

   ui-sref="app.search" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"

The result is that the time is indeed updated, however, the **header of the view is gone**.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this in the routing:

```
  .state('tab.home', {
                        url: '/home',
                        cache: false, //<-- FORCE TO CLEAR CACHE
                        views: {
                            'tab-home': {
                                templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html',
                                controller: 'HomeController'
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: I'm disabling view caching globally with `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`, so `cache` is automatically `false` for any state. Are you suggesting that I shouldn't disable caching globally, but rather on a per-state basis?

Comment: try what i write in the run method... and give also a try to cache:false for each routing

Comment: the trick was indeed to remove the global disabling of the view caching, and add the `cache` attribute on a per-state basis. $templateCache had nothing to do with it. If you update your answer to make this more clear, I will happily accept it. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: updated! ..thnx to you!!..and very happy if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast an event to achieve that. But if you want to keep it like that, you could use a parameter and it would be all right because basically the one in control of the date var is your menu and not your state.
So you could do this:

app.js

```
.state('app.search', {
    url: "/search",
    params:{
        date: new Date()
    },
    views: {
        'menuContent' :{
        templateUrl: "search.html",
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Menu item

```
    <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.search({date: updateDate()})">
      Search
    </ion-item>
```

controllers.js (App controller or specific menu controller)

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.updateDate = updateDate;
  function updateDate(){
   return new Date();
  }
})
```

controllers.js

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.now = $stateParams.date;
})
```

Comment: The date was obviously a very simplified illustration of the problem. Of course, in reality, the controller is much more complex, and I can't just use a parameter. I will update my question to make this more clear.